# sign a contract, secure a contract, close a contract

Tags: word-choice, verbs

Which verb comes before the noun "contract"?

Are there any differences between their formality or usage?

- I have secured a contract for my company.
- I have closed a contract for my company.

Is there any other word choice that we can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meanings are different.

"Sign a contract" means literally that, to put your signature on a contract, thus accepting it and binding you or your company to it.

"Secured a contract" means to have obtained a contract. You might not have signed it yourself (because the CEO likes to sign things?) but you did the work to obtain it.

"Closed a contract" would mean to have made the contract final. Again you might not have actually signed it yourself. Also the term "closed" is almost always used for sales - using it would imply that the contract was for something that the company sells. You would not use it if you secured (or signed) a contract for things other than sales.

Comment: Thanks so much; apart from these options, are there any other verbs or expressions?